# QGIS "template"

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, style

I have a lot of projects in ArcMap that either use a file database .gdb or  shapefiles. All the projects includes layers with the same name but with different data depending of project.
I want to use this data in QGIS but I don´t want to setup the visuals for each project. I know how to use QGIS layer style file .qml but then I have to import the style for each layer in the project (if I use the shapefile). I have not tried using the .gdb data yet.

What I want is to create a project template, with the same structure and style as my ArcMap projects, and then be able to import data to this template.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS project file contains relative paths to layer's sources (if they're files) so if you'll prepare the same directory structure and the same filenames in it (but with different data) and copy project file into the same place in new structure it should open old project with new data...

Second thing is that project file is simple xml so you can update paths using search-replace tool of any text editor.